# multiple declare statements with one creating a temporary table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to include a declare statement referencing a temporary table with other declare statements. It works on its own, but when I add the remaining declare clauses, I get an error...

```
    declare  @meas_enddate datetime,
@meas_startdate datetime, 
@enc_startdate       
datetime, 
@enc_enddate datetime, 
@activestart datetime, 
@activeend datetime, 
@baseline_start datetime,
@baseline_end datetime, 
@Dept as Table (DEPARTMENT_ID numeric(18,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (DEPARTMENT_ID))
INSERT INTO @Dept
SELECT 
'100501201'
UNION SELECT '100208501'
UNION SELECT '100302304'...
```

Comment: You can't. Table variables need to be declared alone.

Answer (score 0):

try seperating table variable creation like below

```
declare @id1 int
declare @id table

(
id int
)
select * from @id
```

instead of

```
declare @id1 int,
 @id table

(
id int
)
select * from @id
```

this has been mentioned in Docs :[DECLARE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql)

> When declaring table variables, the table variable must be the only variable being declared in the DECLARE statement.

Comment: when I do that it tells me that the first one must be declared because it only reads the second declare clause

Comment: so, in other words, it can't be done with other declare statements?

Answer (score 0):

Try this notice the semicolon after @baseline_end and delcare in front of @Dept

```
 declare  @meas_enddate datetime,
 @meas_startdate datetime, 
 @enc_startdate  datetime, 
 @enc_enddate datetime, 
 @activestart datetime, 
 @activeend datetime, 
 @baseline_start datetime,
 @baseline_end datetime; 
 declare @Dept as Table (DEPARTMENT_ID numeric(18,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (DEPARTMENT_ID))
 INSERT INTO @Dept
 SELECT 
 '100501201'
 UNION SELECT '100208501'
 UNION SELECT '100302304'
```

Comment: what is the select * from @dept for?

Comment: Oh, I just did that to see the rows inserted when I tried it. I will delete it.